# Writing Memory to Process

Tags: c++, emulation

I'm trying to write a float value into a video game emulator called Dolphin. I have a spread sheet of memory addresses for a specific game I'd like to be able to change the values at those address. Dolphin has a debug setting and i'm able to look at the games memory on the fly but whenever I try to run my program the value at the memory address does not change

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float newValue = 22;
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(0, "Dolphin 5.0-321");

    if(hWnd == 0) {
        cerr << "Cannot Find Window." << endl;
    } else {
        DWORD pId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &pId);
        HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pId);

        if(!hProc) {
            cerr << "Cannot Open Process." << endl;
        } else {
            int isSuccessful = WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID)0x81118DF0, &newValue, (DWORD)sizeof(newValue), NULL);
            if (isSuccessful) {
                clog << "Process Memory Written." << endl;
            } else {
                cerr << "Cannot Write Process Memory." << endl;
            }
            CloseHandle(hProc);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming that `WriteProcessMemory()` is failing, have you tried calling `GetLastError()` to get the extended error code?

Comment: Are you sure that's the memory address *in Dolphin*, not in the game itself? A gamecube emulator is different from a real gamecube, and what the game thinks is address 0x8118DF0 might actually be an entirely different address, like 0x6234AAA8. (Part of the emulator's job is translating between these addresses)

Answer (score 0):

Dolphin in an emulator, if you're using it's debug function it may not be providing actual real memory addresses, but rather the addresses relative to the emulated system not your Windows operating system.  Think of it kinda like a virtual machine, the dolphin emulator is running a guest operating system and you're writing to memory from the host Windows OS.

If you've located those addresses by reversing the game from the host OS then you can write to those addresses without much issue.

There is no guarantee that writing to the variables address will have the effect you're looking for, it's possible that it gets overwritten by some other code.

Lastly, if you have the correct address for the virtual memory of the dolphin process and you have tested that it changes correctly with a tool like Cheat Engine, the last problem that could arise is that you're not running your C++ project as administrator.  Once doing so, it should work without issue.